# PostgreSQL if else syntax error

Tags: postgresql, if-statement

i try a query that runs on mssql however does not run postgreSQL...

SQL Query is..

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Kategoriler WHERE KategoriId = 119)
    BEGIN 
   SELECT * FROM Kategoriler
    END
    ELSE
   SELECT * FROM Adminler
```

i searched it and i found in stackoverflow

```
DO
   $BODY$
   BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM orders) THEN
              DELETE from orders;
        ELSE 
              INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1,2,3);
        END IF;
   END;
   $BODY$
```

but i do not want to use DO or, $body etc... I do not want to write any function or other etc...

i want to write only if else statement in postgreSQL... Please help me...

Comment: Your first block of code isnt a SQL query. It is a SQL procedure, like the second block.

Comment: what you are asking for is not possible in PostgreSQL.  However, if you can tell us what your goal is, what you are trying to ultimately accomplish, we can probably provide an alternative.

Comment: In future please always mention your **exact PostgreSQL version** in questions; see `select version()`.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you might read about Postgresql's _inheritance_ capabilities to see if they would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Kategoriler
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM Adminler
WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM Kategoriler WHERE KategoriId = 119)
```

Will only work if `Kategoriler` and `Adminler` have same structure. Otherwise you need to specify list of fields instead of `*`

Answer (score 3):

T-SQL supports some procedural statement like IF. PostgreSQL doesn't support it, so you cannot rewrite your query to postgres simply. Sometime you can use Igor's solution, sometime you can use plpgsql (functions) and sometime you have to modify your application and move procedural code from server to  client.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to know if a record existed.

I had to write a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pro_device_exists(vdn character varying)
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tags WHERE device_name = upper(vdn)) THEN
          return true;
    ELSE 
          return false;
    END IF;
END; $function$
```

Then I was able to call this function in my code ... just a portion of my code

```
            if pro_device_exists(vdn) then
                update tags
                set device_id = 11 where device_id = pro_device_id(vdn) and tag_type=10;            
                update tags
                set device_id = pro_device_id(vdn) where tag_id = vtag_id;
                vmsg = (select 'Device Now set to ' || first_name || ' ' || last_name from tags where tag_id=vtag_id);
                vaction = 'Refresh Device Data';
            else
                vmsg = 'Device is not registered on this system';
                vaction = 'No Nothing';
            end if;
```

Comment: Please format the code in your question appropriately.